# Spectral series' formula of a given atom (other than hydrogen-like)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-electrodynamics, atomic-physics, spectroscopy, quantum-optics

The [hydrogen spectral series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_spectral_series) is given by the Rydberg formula:

> The energy differences between levels in the Bohr model, and hence the
>   wavelengths of emitted/absorbed photons, is given by the Rydberg
>   formula:
>
> $${1 \over \lambda} = R \left( {1 \over (n^\prime)^2} - {1 \over n^2}
>  \right) \qquad \left( R = 1.097373 \times 10^7 \ \mathrm{m}^{-1}
>  \right)$$ where $n$ is the upper energy level, $n'$ is the lower
>   energy level, and $R$ is the Rydberg constant.

There is a similar formula for every [hydrogen-like atom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen-like_atom).

**Question**:  Is there a theoretic formula for the spectral series of a given atom (other than hydrogen-like)?   Else, why, what are the difficulties?

Comment: See also this close post: [How can we describe the electrons of multi-electron atoms (i.e. not Hydrogen) when equations/analytic solutions only exist for Hydrogen?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68995/26397)

Comment: See also the wiki page: [List of quantum-mechanical systems with analytical solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_quantum-mechanical_systems_with_analytical_solutions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are, in general, no closed form solutions (aka formulas) for the spectra of multi-electron atoms. There are reasonably precise formulas for special cases, like approximate values of x-ray transitions from inner shell electrons, though. Unlike in case of hydrogen and Rydberg atoms, which can be treated as a non-relativistic one-body problems (i.e. for which the Schroedinger equation is a good approximation), no such simplification exists for atoms with Z>2 and more than one electron. Precise calculation of spectral properties of heavy atoms requires a fully relativistic treatment of a quantum mechanical many-body problem. The correct theoretical framework for that is quantum electrodynamics (QED), which is very complex and can only produce numerical results.

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise about the complexity of QED? Is the QED equation "not solvable" for the helium or even for the hydrogen without simplification? What are the mathematical obstructions for finding solutions (no way to find solutions as Fourier series, analytic functions...)?

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux: not even the Schrodinger equation is soluble for atoms with more than one electron. However we can use numerical methods to construct very accurate approximations. CuriousOne mentions QFT because for heavy atoms the energy of the inner shell electrons is so high that their velocity becomes relativistic. Since Schrodinger's equation is non-relativistic it no longer gives an accurate description of the atom. Actually we can use relativistic QM, so strictly speaking QFT isn't needed.

Comment: @JohnRennie: Thank you for this comment! So if I understand well, the Schrödinger equation could also be a very good approximation for the helium. It's a good approximation up to $Z=$ what? What are the mathematical obstruction for solving the Schrödinger equation with more than one electron?

Comment: @JohnRennie: is there a conjecture for the spectral series' formula of the Helium (and other atoms)?

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux: there is no formula for the spectral series in multielectron atoms. The transition energies can only be calculated numerically.

Comment: @JohnRennie:  yes but perhaps that the numerical computation shows a pattern from which we could *conjecture* a formula.

Comment: @JohnRennie: In fact, the spectrum of an atom is theoretically the whole strip, but with inconstant intensities. The graph shows peaks but the intensity of a given wavelength is never zero, isn't it? So  there is not a discrete series (and an hypothetical conjectural formula for it), but a continuous function (very irregular); unless quantum effects as Planck scale or zero-point energy, impose a discrete pattern, cutting small irregularities and giving wavelengths with intensity zero. **Let me know if this comment deserve its own post**.

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux: in principle the spectrum is zero between peaks. In practice spectra always contain background light e.g. from black body radiation.

Comment: @Sebastien Palcoux: I would agree with John Rennie about the absence of exact solutions for all but the most trivial case of the quantum mechanical two body problem. Curiously, nature has given us an enormous gift, because the hydrogen spectrum allowed Erwin Schroedinger to guess the equation named after him, which gave us an enormous insight into the structure of quantum mechanics. Without this one, highly symmetric case, we might have been guessing around a lot longer, before someone would have come up with the equation, which made everything that came thereafter easier to understand.