# Is central field approximation perfect for alkalis?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atomic-physics, orbitals

In my atomic theory lecture notes it always says the central field approximation is 'excellent' for alkali atoms due to the spherical symmetry of the core electrons and the $s$-shell of the valence electron. It also says therefore that the perturbation due to the residual electric field is 'essentially 0'.

My question is, why are they using the words 'excellent' and 'essentially' when it looks like in this case the central field should be *perfect*. What effects are they assuming that break this?

Comment: Electron shell theory is great for hydrogen, but it doesn't model electron interactions. We should have some existing questions about this...

Comment: These may be helpful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/224108/123208 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/238180/123208 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68995/123208

Comment: The one valence electron s-shell has non-vanishing propability at $r=0$ right at the core region.